# Creating list of users when developing an organisational hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

So I have to build a hierarchy whereby the admin can create Teams and sub-teams. There can be infinite sub-teams and each Team has to have a manager that is already a member of it's parent team (but not the manager of it's parent team).

My issue is this: **How do I create a list of users for the admin to choose from (when creating a sub-team) whereby the user is neither a manager nor a member of any of that sub-teams parent teams?**

I am currently using Linq to SQL in ASP.NET, and my database schema contains is as follows: `Team` - `TeamUser` - `User`

`Team` contains fields such as TeamId, TeamName, ParentTeamId and ManagerId. `TeamUser` is made up of TeamId and UserId and `User` is made up of UserId and name and contact info etc.

At the moment my code looks like this to get the list into a `SelectList`

```
ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => db.TeamUsers.Where(t => t.TeamId == id && t.UserId == u.UserId).Count() == 0), "UserId", "FirstName");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method receives a subteam and:

1. Marks the manager ineligible,
2. Traverses up the parents of the subteam, marking all users in parent teams as ineligible
3. Then returns a List of ids of users who have not been marked ineligible.

Here's the code:

```
public static List<int> GetEligibleUsersForTeam(Team subTeam)
{
    List<int> ineligibleUsers = new List<int>();
    ineligibleUsers.Add(subTeam.ManagerId);
    Team parent = db.Teams.Find(subTeam.ParentTeamId);
    while (parent != null) {
        ineligibleUsers.AddRange(parent.Users.Select(x = x.Id).ToList());
        Team parent = db.Teams.Find(parent.ParentTeamId);
    }
    return db.Users.AsEnumerable().Where(x => ineligibleUsers.Contains(x.Id) == false).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I don't have the entity model, obviously.  Hoping that my representation of the model is reasonably accurate.  Also, you could adapt to return a List of users, not ids, as needed.

Comment: Your representation of the model is actually perfect, i'll give this a shot now.

Comment: Also, there's a potential problem if you're root level team does not have a ParentTeamId of null.  Sometimes in these scenarios, the root level node has it's parent set to itself. You may need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the return statement. Will get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about the fact that you are having trouble with the last statement, I could see why.  Try it like this instead:  `db.Users.Where(x => ineligibleUsers.Contains(x.Id) == false).ToList();`.  If you have a large number of users, that might not be an ok solution.  The problem you are having is that the Contains that I wrote cannot be translated back to SQL because ineligibleUsers does not exist on the SQL side. Sorry about that.  I didn't think that through enough.

Comment: I don't think you changed anything in your new suggestion? lol

Comment: Oops. don't know what happened there. I just now made the change in the answer, by adding AsEnumerable(). See if that helps.

Comment: It does work :P I'll post my final code for the benefit of others but this is what got me there.